# To close the system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am studying stochastic equations. Lectures use a term "to close a system of ODE" or "the system of ODE can be closed only if coefficients"... What does it mean?

Comment: This needs more context. It could be related to differential forms and first integrals, but could also be something completely different.

Comment: It might mean that the system of the ODEs can be solved by some [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)

Comment: Here are more details: $$\frac{d}{dt} <X^{n}(t)>=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k}<X^{n-k}(t) a_{k}(X(t))>$$ can only be closed if functions $a_{k}(x)$ are polynomials in $x$ of degree $\leq k$. I would appreciate clarification what this means.

Comment: Are these expectations like in the bra-ket symbolism of physics or quadratic variances like in Ito calculus?

Comment: What is $X^n(t)$? The $n$th component of some vector or series, the $n$th iteration of $X$ (unlikely), some unusual notation for the $n$th derivative? Is there some expectation that $X^n$ is polynomial or polynomially bounded with some degree expressed in $n$?

Comment: $X(t)$ is a random variable, brackets <> is a symbol for the expectation (n-th moment of a random variable inside the brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a system of ODEs:

$$
\frac{dm_1}{dt} = f_1(m_1, m_2 ... m_k, ...m_n)
$$
$$
\frac{dm_2}{dt} = f_2(m_1, m_2 ... m_k, ...m_n)
$$
$$...$$
$$
\frac{dm_n}{dt} = f_n(m_1, m_2 ... m_k, ...m_n)
$$

closing is finding a function H such that all but a few variables are expressed in this form
$$
\frac{dm_1}{dt} = f_1(m_1, m_2 ... m_k, H(m_1, m_2 ... m_k))
$$
$$
\frac{dm_2}{dt} = f_2(m_1, m_2 ... m_k, H(m_1, m_2 ... m_k))
$$
$$...$$
$$
\frac{dm_k}{dt} = f_k(m_1, m_2 ... m_k, H(m_1, m_2 ... m_k))
$$

It simplifies handling of systems with infinite many variables